# There can be only one 'master' directive

Tags: asp.net

Im not a expert in asp.net

```
Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPageResult.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPageResult" %> 
Line 2:  <%@ MasterPageFile="master1.master" %>
```

Parser Error Message: There can be only one 'master' directive.

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

This means that there should only be one `<%@ Master ... %>` in your file.
It can also mean that you may have both `<%@ Page ... %>` and `<%@ Master ... %>` directives in the same file.

I guess combining the lines like this will fix your issue:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPageResult.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPageResult"  MasterPageFile="master1.master" %>
```

For documentation about master pages in ASP.NET, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.140).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228176(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That doesn't mean you can have only one `<%@ .... %>`. You can have `@Import`, `@assembly`, `@implements` etc

Comment: @TusharGupta you're right, I missed the `Master` in between.

Comment: @shgan please accept it as a answer if it solved your issue by clicking on right symbol.